# jquery fadein child issue

Tags: jquery, html

Just a short question, probably some syntax mistake, but I can't seem to find it. I have a function that animates a div's height and width using an id. I'm also trying to `fadeIn()` the child paragraph using `$(this).find('p')`. Is this possible? I looked around and tried different syntaxes like `children()`. Here's the code concerned:

[JS]

```
$('#menu_item_1').hover(function () {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "255px",
        marginTop: "-100px",
        marginLeft: "-100px"
    });

    $(this).find('p').fadeIn();

}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "200px",
        height: "155px",
        marginTop: "0",
        marginLeft: "0"
    });
});
```

[HTML]

```
<div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_1">
       <h5>Home</h5>
       <p>Shows this page</p>
</div>
```

Also, a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/w0uu5t7b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/p1sfsq0d/1/)

Remove the `opacity:0` and make it `display:none`

And the `$(this).find('p').fadeIn();` refers to the this of hover function and not jQuery.

So its better to store jQuery reference as `var that = this` and use it as a closure inside the hover function.

So on mouse enter you do `$(that).find('p').fadeIn();` and on mouse leave you do `$(that).find('p').fadeIn();` as simple as it can get.

P.S Read up more about javascript closures :P

Comment: Wow. See, I knew it was simple like that. I'll explain; I tried animating the opacity before but thought it might be easier to just fadeIn the paragraph. But I didn't change the opacity. Pretty dumb I guess, but thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Awesome! Please accept the answer as your query is answered ;)

Comment: Haha there's a waiting period of like 12 minutes, which is almost over.

Comment: @Ajey, fwiw, the reason is not that a closure was created and `this` needed to be preserved https://jsfiddle.net/p1sfsq0d/2/